# TCPServer / TCP Client File transfer issue: 0 bytes

Tags: java, tcp

I can transfer the files but when I want to open them it says that the file is corrupted (because its 0 bytes long). T

When I start the TCPServer it waits for clients and accepts them and then sends the file to them. The client recives the file (but not all of it I assume ?) When I tried this with a picture.png that is 10 kb it worked. With anything else, it does not. I also did port forwarding (else the client couldnt get the file)

THIS IS THE TCPSERVER:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPServer {

    private final static String fileToSend = "C:/Users/Tim/Desktop/P&P/Background music for P&P/Rock.wav";

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        while (true) {
            ServerSocket welcomeSocket = null;
            Socket connectionSocket = null;
            BufferedOutputStream outToClient = null;

            try {
                welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(3222);
                connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
                outToClient = new BufferedOutputStream(
                        connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Do exception handling
            }

            if (outToClient != null) {
                File myFile = new File(fileToSend);
                byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];

                FileInputStream fis = null;

                try {
                    fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    // Do exception handling
                }
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

                try {
                    bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                    outToClient.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                    outToClient.flush();
                    outToClient.close();
                    connectionSocket.close();

                    // File sent, exit the main method
                    return;
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Do exception handling
                }
            }
        }
    }
}





HERE IS THE TCP CLIENT: 

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

class TCPClient {

    private final static String serverIP = "123.123.123.123";
    private final static int serverPort = 3222;
    private final static String fileOutput = "C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/check.wav";

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        while (true) {

            byte[] aByte = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;

            Socket clientSocket = null;
            InputStream is = null;

            try {
                clientSocket = new Socket(serverIP, serverPort);
                is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Do exception handling
            }

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            if (is != null) {

                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(fileOutput);
                    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                    bytesRead = is.read(aByte, 0, aByte.length);

                    do {
                        baos.write(aByte);
                        bytesRead = is.read(aByte);
                    } while (bytesRead != -1);

                    bos.write(baos.toByteArray());
                    bos.flush();
                    bos.close();
                    clientSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Do exception handling
                }
            }

            // Music is played here
            try {

                AudioInputStream input = AudioSystem
                        .getAudioInputStream(new File(fileOutput));
                SourceDataLine line = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(input
                        .getFormat());
                line.open(input.getFormat());
                line.start();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                    line.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                line.drain();
                line.stop();
                line.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactored your client code a little bit:

- no need for the ByteArrayOutputStream when already using a BufferedOutputStream
- use bytesRead for byte array offset

This worked for me:

```
if (is != null)
        {

            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
            try
            {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileOutput));
                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

                while ((bytesRead = is.read(aByte)) != -1)
                {
                    bos.write(aByte, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                bos.flush();
                bos.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Now this happend:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at TCPClient.main(TCPClient.java:57)
java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileReader.getFMT(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at TCPClient.main(TCPClient.java:74).